# How can i implement an estimated reading time feature in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to integrate estimated reading time in a wordpress theme and I can't seem to get this to work. I took the code from here http://wptavern.com/estimated-time-to-read-this-post-eternity . I pasted this into functions.php

```
function bm_estimated_reading_time() {

    $post = get_post();

    $words = str_word_count( strip_tags( $post->post_content ) );
    $minutes = floor( $words / 120 );
    $seconds = floor( $words % 120 / ( 120 / 60 ) );

    if ( 1 < = $minutes ) {
        $estimated_time = $minutes . ' minute' . ($minutes == 1 ? '' : 's') . ', ' . $seconds . ' second' . ($seconds == 1 ? '' : 's');
    } else {
        $estimated_time = $seconds . ' second' . ($seconds == 1 ? '' : 's');
    }

    return $estimated_time;

}
```

and then called it

```
<p class="ert"><?php bm_estimated_reading_time() ?></p>
```

in content-single.php, right after the author link and nothing gets displayed. If I inspect the post in chrome I can see the paragraph, but it is empty. What am I doing wrong, or what else should I be doing instead ?

Comment: Well, neither your function nor your template code actually echoes anything, so that's probably why nothing's coming out...

Comment: Maybe try `<?php echo bm_estimated_reading_time() ?>`

Comment: First of all, thanks @MattGibson . I am new to programming, but now that you mentioned it, I feel like an idiot for not noticing this. It seems obvious now. I should have been able to see this by myself. Thanks again for pointing it out man. It prints like I wanted it to now.

Comment: @Kaladan ok I added an answer for closure. +1 to Matt for noticing it first.

Comment: No problem. I'd accept Popnoodles' solution, looks like exactly what you need.

Comment: Why was this closed? The question is valid. Not realising that you need to echo the response is not a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function returns a value. You're not echoing the returned value.

```
<?php echo bm_estimated_reading_time() ?>
```

Comment: +1 for explicitly using echo :-D

Comment: Yes; it's worth considering the use of `<?=` for a project—there's nothing intrinsically bad about it—but for WordPress code I'd always use `echo`, as WordPress core always uses echo, presumably because that means it can be deployed more reliably anywhere without worrying about the server's PHP version/short_open_tags setting. So if you end up developing themes and plugins for distribution, it's a habit worth adopting.